# Not able to see menu option when I open my app in android

Tags: android

Emulator shows menu item.

Running .apk in tablet want show it.

Device: Samsung Android 4.1

```
Code:

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StockInfo.this,chart.class);
            intent.putExtra("companycode", companyCode);
            Log.e("code", companyCode);
            startActivity(intent);
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps the targetSdkVersion is > 11, so the menu button is not shown? http://techblog.rokoder.com/android-missing-menu-button/

Comment: try changing return true to return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

Comment: No use by changing it

Answer (score 0):

if your device has hardware menu button , menu item will not show up, you can crack it by adding the below code in oncreate.. In tablets it will show menu item as tablets doent contains menu hardware button

```
        try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: My device as no hardware button.

Comment: It might not have a hardware button, but a majority of Samsung tablets (except for very recent models) have a "menu" softkey at the bottom. That is probably why your menu is not showing.

Comment: doesn't work.I add your piece of code  on create before my existing code.